# Fullcalendar: How to add time(hours, minutes) to create events form?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Then I try to create new event from daily or weeks view, the start time added automatically after clicking in the appropriate field. But when setting the end time of an event, only the date is available, but not time.
[image]

How can I add also the ability to select the time in the popup window?

My current fullcalendar script settings:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
              var clickDate = date.format();
              $('#start-date').val(clickDate);
              $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            },
            theme: true,
        header: {
        left:   'title',
        center: '',
        right:  'today prev,next agendaDay,agendaWeek, month'
    },

    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    //date number are clickable
    navLinks: true,
    //minute delta display separate
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    eventLimit: true,

            eventSources: [

    // your event source
    {
      events: [
                {% for i in events %}
                {
                    title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                    start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                    end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',

                },
                {% endfor %}

            ],
      color: 'red',     // an option!
      textColor: 'white' // an option!
    }

    // any other event sources...

  ]
        });
        //add new event
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
        effect: 'drop',
        duration: 500
    },
    hide: {
        effect: 'clip',
        duration: 500
    }
});
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy.mm.dd"
    });
    });

</script>
```

And my html form (Iam using Django framework for backend)

```
<div class=" container clearfix mt- mb-5">
    <div id='calendar'></div>
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
         <form method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="event_name">Event name</label>
              {%  render_field  event_form.event_name class="form-control" id='event_name' %}
            <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="event_name" > -->
          </div>
             <div class="form-group">
             <label for="start-date">Event start</label>
              {%  render_field  event_form.start_date class="form-control datepicker" id='start-date' %}

             <!--<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="start-date"> -->
          </div>
             <div class="form-group">
            <label for="end-date">Event end</label>
                 {%  render_field  event_form.end_date class="form-control datepicker" id='end-date' %}
             <!--<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="end-date"> -->
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create event</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: I can't see your HTML, but I would guess you need to add another textbox into the dialog, where the user can enter the time. At the moment it appears that you only have a date field.

Comment: Alternatively, you can stop using `dayClick` for accepting user input, and instead use `[select](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/select-callback)`, which is the way fullCalendar intends you to allow users to place events into the calendar. Then, if they are using a view such as "agenda" or "timeline" which includes times of day in the view, they can click-and-drag to select the period of time the event should cover. As you can see in that documentation link, the callback then provides you with the start and end times of the area selected by the user.

Comment: Here's a demo of that from the fullCalendar site: https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001 . Move to the "week" view and then click and drag over an area of the calendar. You'll see it runs the "select" callback, and reports the start and end time of the area you dragged over.

Comment: @ADyson I updated my answer  html code. I read the documentation, but could not understand what I need to change. I do backend and my knowledge of js is very weak.

Comment: Try replacing the dayClick part with this: `select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) { $('#start-date').val(start.format()); $('#end-date').val(end.format()); $('#dialog').dialog('open'); },` . And now the user can click and drag to select the length of time they want the event to take. (Of course, if they do this in a view like "month" which has no times on it, then fullCalendar will make start and end just be the same date, with no times involved. For it to be useful, it needs to be used in agenda or timeline view)

Comment: @ADyson Pasted your code, but now there is no any reaction when click

Comment: Sorry I forgot, you have to add `selectable: true` option as well. Did you study the CodePen link I gave?? It would show you. Anyway here's a demo using my code specifically, with a minimal version of your dialog: http://jsfiddle.net/x4tb6fq0/1/ . Now you may find that you have a problem with your datepicker because there are times inside the field as well. So you may want to consider a) splitting each date and time into two fields, b) not using a datepicker, or c) just making the date/time as read-only, since the user has already chosen these values by dragging.

Comment: Cool, this is what I need. Thank!